# Get all the related posts except the current post using WPGraphQl in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, graphql, wp-graphql

I'm trying to grab the **related posts** except the current post using **WPGraphQL**. My thought is to **exclude** the **ID** of the current post and display all related blog posts within the category.

I'm new to **GraphQL**, I don't know how to figure out to solve it. is this possible in GraphQL? Please help

```
query MyQuery {
  category(idType: DATABASE_ID, id: 1) {
    posts {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          title
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `where.notIn` argument on the `posts` connection field under `category`, like so.

```
query MyQuery($currentPostId: ID) {
  category(idType: DATABASE_ID, id: 1) {
    posts(where: {notIn: [$id]}) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          title
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```